# Creating variables from different line types imported from text file

Tags: c++, variables, input

I'm trying to import data from a text file and assign it to variables so that I can analyse it with functions.  The data is in the following format:

```
Run 141544 event 5
Njets 0
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1 dptinv: 0.000370146
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1 dptinv: 0.00038302

Run 141544 event 7
Njets 1
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1 dptinv: 0.000406393
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1 dptinv: 0.000399279
```

...
There are around 15000 entries, each with four lines.  On each line, the values are delimited by spaces, and between each entry, there is a blank line.  Because each line of the entry is in a different format, I wrote a loop to separate the cases.  The problem that I'm having is that something appears to be wrong with the code that assigns variables.  When I use the loop
to output lines of a certain type, everything runs perfectly.  But once I try to break up each line into variables and assign and print the variables, the program prints the same line multiple times and crashes.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct rowtype1 // structure of lines containing run data
{
    string runnumber;
    string eventnumber;
};

struct rowtype2 // structure of lines containing data for muon1 and muon2
{
    string ptvalue1;
    string etavalue1;
    string phivalue1;
    string massvalue1;
};

vector<rowtype1> row1values;
vector<rowtype2> row2values;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("/Users/Edward/Downloads/muons.txt");

    if (inData.is_open())
    {
        while ( inData.good() )
        {
            while (getline(inData,line))
            {
                if (line[0] == 'N') // recognizes and skips blank lines
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (line[1] == 'u') // recognizes lines containing run information
                {
                    istringstream ss(line);
                    istream_iterator<string> begin(ss), end;
                    vector<string> words(begin, end);
                    rowtype1 s { words[1], words[3]};
                    row1values.push_back(s);
                    for(auto && s : row1values)
                        cout << "run " << s.runnumber << " " << "event " << s.eventnumber << "\n";
                }
                else if (line[1] == '1') // recognizes lines containing muon1 information
                {
                    istringstream ss(line);
                    istream_iterator<string> begin(ss), end;
                    vector<string> words(begin, end);
                    rowtype2 s { words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5] };
                    row2values.push_back(s);
                    for(auto && s : row2values)
                        cout << "m1 " << s.ptvalue1 << " " << s.etavalue1 << " " << s.phivalue1 << " " << s.massvalue1 << "\n";
                }
                else if (line[1] == '2') // recognizes lines containing muon2 information
                {
                  istringstream ss(line);
                    istream_iterator<string> begin(ss), end;
                    vector<string> words(begin, end);
                    rowtype2 s { words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5] };
                    row2values.push_back(s);
                    for(auto && s : row2values)
                        cout << "m2 " << s.ptvalue1 << " " << s.etavalue1 << " " << s.phivalue1 << " " << s.massvalue1 << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        inData.close();
    }
    return 0;
};
```

To test if the variables are being assigned correctly, I had the code output their values.  Instead of looping through the rows and outputting the variables, the output looks like this:

```
run 141544 event 5
Run 141544 event 5
m1 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
run 141544 event 5
run 141544 event 7
Run 141544 event 7
m1 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m1 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
m1 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1
m2 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
m2 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1
m2 238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1
run 141544 event 5
run 141544 event 7
run 141572 event 2
```

Comment: Please don't use global variables =/

Comment: What is that ==> `vector<double> a, vector<double> b);` Specifically the mystery-right-paren.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: No errors appear in the debugger.  It's just that in the output, all of the lines are jumbled together:                                   run 141544 event 5
Run 141544 event 5
m1 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
run 141544 event 5
run 141544 event 7
Run 141544 event 7
m1 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m1 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
m1 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1
m2 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1
m2 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1
m2 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1
m2 238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1
run 141544 event 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many issues with your code that I won't go into detail to address.

Mainly, I think your issue is related to the fact that **you didn't parse the file correctly, and your variables are misaligned in assignments.**

While attempting to fix it and making it more modular, I simply rewrote it to the following (**I did not perform any checks - that's something you can do for yourself.** *All data was assumed to be correct.*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> ivec;
typedef std::vector<double> dvec;
typedef std::vector<std::string> svec;


void get_runs_events(std::string const &varstr, ivec &runs, ivec &events) {
  std::istringstream iss(varstr);
  std::string t1, t2;

  int run = 0, event = 0;

  if (iss >> t1 >> run >> t2 >> event) {
    runs.push_back(run);
    events.push_back(event);
  }
}

void get_njets(std::string const &varstr, ivec &njets) {
  std::istringstream iss(varstr);
  std::string t1;

  int njet;

  if (iss >> t1 >> njet) {
    njets.push_back(njet);
  }
}

void set_m_params(std::string const &varstr, dvec &pt, dvec &eta, dvec &phi, dvec &m, dvec &dptinv) {
  std::string dpt = "dptinv:";
  std::string pre_str = varstr.substr(varstr.find('=') + 1);
  std::string str = pre_str.substr(0, pre_str.find(dpt));

  std::string dpt_value = pre_str.substr(pre_str.find(dpt) + dpt.length());

  double m_pt, m_eta, m_phi, m_m, m_dptinv;

  std::istringstream iss(str);

  if (iss >> m_pt >> m_eta >> m_phi >> m_m) {
    pt.push_back(m_pt);
    eta.push_back(m_eta);
    phi.push_back(m_phi);
    m.push_back(m_m);
  }

  iss.str(dpt_value);
  iss.clear();

  if (iss >> m_dptinv) {
    dptinv.push_back(m_dptinv);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream ifile("text", std::ifstream::in);
  std::string temp;

  ivec runs, events, njets;
  dvec m1_pt, m1_eta, m1_phi, m1_m, m1_dptinv;
  dvec m2_pt, m2_eta, m2_phi, m2_m, m2_dptinv;

  svec raw;

  if (ifile.is_open()) {

    while(std::getline(ifile, temp)) {
      raw.push_back(temp);
    }

    int i = 0;

    //now iterate over the raw data and accordingly, fill the containers
    //Why i % 5? Because although you said your lines repeat every 4 lines,
    //in actuality, they repeat every FIVE lines as the blank line counts as one.
    //There are many ways to go about this, but my implementation reads the entire file
    //line by line and skips the 5th line, or in the case of a i % 5 case, that
    //would be i % 5 == 4. Since that's assumed to be invalid, I ignored it entirely,
    //hence my code, as shown below.
    for (svec::const_iterator it = raw.begin(); it != raw.end(); ++it, ++i) {
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        get_runs_events(*it, runs, events);
      }
      else if (i % 5 == 1) {
        get_njets(*it, njets);
      }
      else if (i % 5 == 2) {
        set_m_params(*it, m1_pt, m1_eta, m1_phi, m1_m, m1_dptinv);
      }
      else if (i % 5 == 3) {
        set_m_params(*it, m2_pt, m2_eta, m2_phi, m2_m, m2_dptinv);
      }
    }

    //now output the information to see that it is correct
    for (i = 0; i < runs.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << runs[i] << " " << events[i] << " " << njets[i] << "\n";
      std::cout << m1_pt[i] << " " << m1_eta[i] << " " << m1_phi[i] << " " << m1_m[i] << " " << m1_dptinv[i] << "\n";
      std::cout << m2_pt[i] << " " << m2_eta[i] << " " << m2_phi[i] << " " << m2_m[i] << " " << m2_dptinv[i] << "\n\n";
    }
  }
  else {
    exit(1);
  }

  ifile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Using this data (modified slightly from your original):

```
Run 141544 event 5
Njets 0
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1 dptinv: 0.000370146
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1 dptinv: 0.00038302

Run 141545 event 7
Njets 1
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1 dptinv: 0.000406393
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1 dptinv: 0.00039927

Run 141546 event 5
Njets 0
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1 dptinv: 0.000370146
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1 dptinv: 0.00038302

Run 141547 event 7
Njets 1
m1: pt,eta,phi,m= 281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1 dptinv: 0.000406393
m2: pt,eta,phi,m= 238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1 dptinv: 0.00039927
```

**You get the correct results of the following ordering:**

- 1st row: **{run} {event} {njet}**
- 2nd row: **{m1 pt} {m1 eta} {m1 phi} {m1 m} {m1 dptinv}**
- 3rd row: **{m2 pt} {m2 eta} {m2 phi} {m2 m} {m2 dptinv}**

And the following output:

```
141544 5 0
231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1 0.000370146
222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1 0.00038302

141545 7 1
281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1 0.000406393
238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1 0.00039927

141546 5 0
231.277 0.496237 -2.22082 0.1 0.000370146
222.408 -0.198471 0.942319 0.1 0.00038302

141547 7 1
281.327 -0.489914 1.12498 0.1 0.000406393
238.38 0.128715 -2.07527 0.1 0.00039927
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if..else if..` to distinguish all line "types", but at the end of each if block you add `continue`. Either use `if.. continue` (preferred, I think), or one single long block of `if .. else if ..`.

Anyway, is the problem that your `run x` lines are duplicated? There is a line

```
cout << line;
```

at the end of the "run" case test. Is that your problem?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I just tried deleting the continue statements, but the problem doesn't seem to be fixed.  I've updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: My remark on `continue` is about programming style. Using the same style throughout will make your code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you don't check that `line` is non-empty before you attempt to access it (e.g. `line[0]`, `line[1]`) on each iteration. The blank lines in your data file will result in `line` being empty, so accessing it with `operator[]` will produce undefined behavior ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5b%5d/)).

Thus, the first check inside of your main loop should be changed from

```
if (line[0] == 'N') { continue; }
```

to

```
if (line.empty() || line[0] == 'N') { continue; }
```

It would be prudent to include additional validation checks on `line` and `words` to be sure to avoid undefined behavior. For example, you should make sure that the length of `line` is at least 2, and be sure that the resulting `words` vector is of the expected length as well.

With those issues aside, you're seeing duplicated lines for two reasons:

- You're printing the current `line` again in the case that `line[1] == 'u'`: `cout << line;`
- When you hit either a rowtype1 or rowtype2 case, you loop through the entirety of either `row1values` or `row2values` and print **all** of the accumulated rows so far.

Remove `cout << line;` from the rowtype1 case. Then remove the loop `for(auto && s : ... )` (but leave its innards!) from each case so that you are only printing the relevant values for the *current* `s` that was just read in from the file.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: You're welcome! If you're interested, I added another point about validating your input before using it.